# firebase security rules not working as expected

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

i'm trying to understand how security rules structure is working. I have these rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "level1": { //public info
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true,
            "level2": { //private info
              ".read": false,
              ".write": false
              }
        }
    }
}
```

then testing with simulator i expected to have r/w access to level1, and NOT to level2...

but result was i have r/w access to **both** levels. 
How is that? Am i missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you grant (read or write) access on one level, you can not revoke access on a lower level. See this quote from the [Firebase documentation on security](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade):

> **Rules Cascade**
>
> SECURITY AND FIREBASE RULES WORK FROM THE TOP-DOWN
>
> This is a critical concept of understanding Security and Firebase Rules. The child rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.

Comment: oh thanks, my bad. i guess i'll change my structure then